# How to bind CGSize.width in cocoa (Interface Builder)?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, binding, interface-builder

I tried to bind the width value of a CGSize property of a Cocoa application with interface builder.

I set the "model key path" to "windowSize" (my CGSize value) and tried different values in the "Value Transformer field" like "width", or "%{width}@" but when I run the application, it crash with this error "Cannot find value transformer with name {width}@"

Which transformer should i use ?

Comment: `width` is a struct member, not a property.  In order to bind to it, you need a KVO-compliant accessor in your class.

Comment: “Value Transformer” doesn't take a key, key path, or format string. It takes the name of a value transformer (an object that is some kind of NSValueTransformer). If no value transformer already exists for this, you could create one—but if this is meant to be editable, good luck figuring out a way to transform width alone back into a size.

Comment: @CodaFi: True in this case, but [there are exceptions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Key-ValueCodingExtensions/Key-ValueCodingExtensions.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to make custom accessors in some object of yours—e.g., the window controller (which will have to be of a custom subclass of NSWindowController)—and bind to those.

In each accessor, get the window's `frame` or `contentSize`, and either retrieve or change the relevant member of it. In the setter, you then set the adjusted frame or size back where you got it; in the getter, you return the extracted number.

Binding directly to the `width` or `height` of a CGSize value, or to (any part of) the `origin` or `size` of a rectangle, won't work for the reason CodaFi described: You can only bind to properties of objects, and sizes and rectangles (and points) aren't objects.

Although you use the same “dot syntax” (`foo.bar`) for both, there is a distinction between accessing a member of a structure (such as the `width` of an NSSize or a CGSize) and accessing a property of an object (such as the `contentSize` of an NSWindow). You can bind to a property of an object; you cannot bind to a member of a structure.